# Sql find the last non-numeric character in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, find, patindex

How to find last non-numeric character in a string such as "10jnklgm51". In order to find 'm' in the example what is the best simple way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last non-numeric character is the first non-numeric character in the reverse string.  So, something like this:

```
select substring(reverse(str),
                 patindex('%[^0-9]%', reverse(str)),
                 1)
```